# Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite()?

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

Recently i updated wordpress 3.0 automatically. Before update, everything working fine. After the update, page is displayed with error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite() in /home1/servername/public_html/myfolder/mysite/wp-includes/wp-db.php  on line 505

I then overwritten all the files with new version files from FTP. But still I am having the same problem. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

FTP the file `wp-includes/load.php` and `wp-settings.php` and check that;

1. **wp-includes/load.php** line **578** is `function is_multisite()`
2. **wp-settings.php line** line **19** is `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php' );`

If that's all ok, disable any troublemaking plugins by deleting them or temporarily renaming them in your plugins folder.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are using SVN, delete the wp-includes folder and the wp-settings.php file and do and 'svn up'

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```php
if(function_exists('is_multisite'))
```